# Periodic orbit in vector field with positive divergence

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

The Dulac-Bendixson Theorem states that a vector field with positive divergence defined on a 2-connected set cannot have more than one periodic orbit. I am looking for an exemple of a field defined on an open set minus one point, such that the field has positive divergence everywhere and the differential equation defined by such field has a periodic orbit.

Many thanks.

Comment: The [Bendixson-Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) states that a vector field with positive divergence on a simply connected set cannot have a single (nontrivial) periodic orbit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the vector field given in polar coordinates as $(\frac{r -1}{r},1)$, which gives (according to Mathematica)
$$
\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \frac{x+y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\right)
$$
in Cartesian coordinates.  It is defined on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, its divergence is equal to
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} > 0
$$
(again according to Mathematica), and there is a nontrivial periodic orbit.